# I cant seem to use .split right, what am i doing wrong

Tags: java

I am trying to split a read in file and put it into a 2d array. The file has 3 strings on each
      line seperated by a comma, the overall idea is to arrange this with a sorting algorithm but i     cant split the strings, its driving me nuts, can anyone help.

```
/**
 * 
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Example2{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        FileIO reader = new FileIO();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] inputs = reader.load("C:/ratings.csv");
        String[] sep = new String[inputs.length];

        for(int i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
           sep[i]=inputs.split(",");
           System.out.println(sep[i]);
        }

        try{
            reader.save("C://somefile.csv",inputs);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to put a `String[]` where a `String` is expected. (`sep` has a component type of `String`, `String#split` has a return type of `String[]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))is a method in the `String` class, and `inputs` is an array of strings. An array access is expected there. You probably just forgot to add `[i]` in the code. Also, since you are splitting a string in a loop, you are creating a 2D array of strings, which means `sep` should be a `String[][]`. Have a go with this.

```
public class Example2{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        FileIO reader = new FileIO();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] inputs = reader.load("C:/ratings.csv");
        String[][] sep = new String[inputs.length][];

        for(int i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
             sep[i]=inputs[i].split(",");
             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sep[i]));
           }
        }

        // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what are you returning but .split will split sep into a list

this code is correct

```
sep[i]=inputs.split(",");
```

but here is your problem

```
String[] sep = new String[inputs.length];
```

this is 1 dimensional array but you need 2 dimensional array

answer:

```
String[][] sep = new String[inputs.length][];
```

this is just to fix the .split problem

Comment: `inputs.split(",")` is incorrect, unlike what you have mentioned.